# Which GUI is similar to listbox on iphone?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, listbox, interface-builder

I'm trying to move a former app from windows mobile to iphone. Any ideas which GUI in Interface Builder has the similar function as listbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableView is appropriate when you have a list, possibly a quite long one, and you want to navigate a hierarchy by tapping items on the list.

Also look at UIPickerView which is similar to a drop-down list on a combo box. It's not for navigation or long lists.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, there's nothing quite like that on the iPhone. A UITableView, possibly with a "search" field, is the usual solution for long lists of things.

The way that the built-in Mail application does address searches seems pretty useful for most of the places you'd use a Combobox. Take a look at that.